# Select the first row and the last row in aggregation and create 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query that show for each customer who made two or more purchases, view the first and last product purchased:

```
custumerID   | Product ID First purchase | Product ID Last purchase
    10       |            286            |            448
   1033      |            244            |            138
    11       |            265            |            299
```

I succeeded to show all the purchased of customers who made two or more purchases, the ProductID and the date:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Order_Date, Product_ID
FROM Orders
WHERE Customer_ID IN 
(SELECT Customer_ID FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
ORDER BY Customer_ID, (CONVERT(datetime,Order_Date))
```

[image]

How can I select the first row and the last row in aggregation and create 2 columns of them?

Comment: Can you share DDLs for your schema? Or better yet, an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, using `COUNT` and `ROW_NUMBER` as analytic functions.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Customer_ID, Order_Date, Product_ID,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Order_Date) rn_first,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Order_Date DESC) rn_last
    FROM Orders
)

SELECT
    Customer_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN Product_ID END) AS Product_ID_first,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN Product_ID END) AS Product_ID_last
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 2
GROUP BY
    Customer_ID
ORDER BY
    Customer_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have MAX and MIN purchase date on the same date (Customer ID = 10), if the first column is ID I guess with auto increment, you can use this following script for your desired output-

```
SELECT 
Customer_ID,
(SELECT Order_ID FROM your_table WHERE ID =MIN(A.ID)) [Product ID First purchase],
(SELECT Order_ID FROM your_table WHERE ID=MAX(A.ID)) [Product ID Last purchase]
FROM your_table A
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not (yet?) support "first" and "last" functions as aggregation functions.  It does support them as window functions, so you can do:

```
select distinct customer_id,
       first_value(product_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) as first_product,
       first_value(product_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date desc) as last_product
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from orders o2
              where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                    o2.order_date <> o.order_date
             );
```

Or, if you like window functions, you can dispense with the `select distinct` and `exists`:

```
select customer_id, first_product, last_product
from (select o.*,
            first_value(product_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) as first_product,
            first_value(product_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date desc) as last_product,
            count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as cnt,
            row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as seqnum
    ) o
where cnt >= 2 and seqnum = 1;
```

I would phrase the conditional aggregation as:

```
select o.customer_id,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then o.product_id end) as first_product,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then o.product_id end) as last_product
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from orders o
     ) o
group by customer_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

The traditional non-window function method would use two joins:

```
select o.customer_id,
       firsto.product_id as first_product,
       lasto.product_id as last_product
from (select customer_id, min(order_date) as min_od,
             max(order_date) as max_od
      from orders o
      group by customer_id
      having count(*) >= 2
     ) o join
     orders firsto
     on firsto.customer_id = o.customer_id and
        firsto.order_date = o.min_od join
     orders lasto
     on lasto.customer_id = o.customer_id and
        last.order_date = o.max_od;
```

This is actually the most convenient method if you want to get multiple values from each order -- say the amount, payment method, and date in addition to the product.