# Calculate percentage by 2 columns using windows function + partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write query that calculate for each customer his part of the total profit in the year.

I secceded to write this query by using join but I want to write this by windows function + partition.

```
SELECT t1.Customer_ID, t1.Year, [Sum of Profit]/[Total Profit] [Part of Profit]
FROM
(SELECT Customer_ID, DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date) Year, 
SUM(Try_convert(float,Profit)) [Sum of Profit]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer_ID, DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date)) t1
JOIN
(SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date) Year, SUM(Try_convert(float,Profit)) [Total Profit]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date)) t2
ON t1.Year = t2.Year
```

[image]

How can I use windows function + partition to do same query?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303958/calculate-average-between-rows-in-sql-by-using-lag-and-ignore-first-row), or [the one before that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302973/select-the-first-row-and-the-last-row-in-aggregation-and-create-2-columns-in-sql)?  You never accepted any of the thoughtful answers given there, and now you expect the community to invest more time into your current question.

Comment: These questions are different, I try to learn from these questions and answers.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, just know that you generally expected to make use of and reward the helpful answers that you receive here.  Keep in mind that most of us are _volunteers_; we have jobs too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in an aggregation query:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, YEAR(Order_Date) as Year, 
       SUM(Try_convert(float, Profit)) as [Sum of Profit],
       (SUM(Try_convert(float, Profit)) /
        SUM(SUM(Try_convert(float, Profit))) OVER ()
       ) as ratio
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer_ID, YEAR(Order_Date)
```